# Download multiple file using AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to download multiple file using AsyncTask.
I start each download in one AsyncTask with progress bar in notification bar but i face many problems.

1. If i download 4 or 5 files at the same time the one or more files
   interrupted without any reason.
2. If i download 4 or 5 images the one or more images corrupted.

this is the code i used.

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> 
            {
                int nID = 0;
                int nDownloadCounter = 0;
                public DownloadFile(String sFileName, int nNotificationID) {
                    this.nID = nNotificationID;
                    this.NotificationName = sFileName;
                    this.nDownloadCounter = 0;
                }

                protected void onPreExecute(){
                    this.sDownloadPath = sFilePathWithSubDir;
                    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.app_icon, "Download File", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);

                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
                    File file = new File(this.sDownloadPath + this.NotificationName);
                    sMediaDataType = GSUtilities.sGetFileMIMEType(this.NotificationName);

                    notificationIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    notificationIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), sMediaDataType);

                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

                    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_percent, "0%");
                    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_fileName, this.NotificationName);
                    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 0, false);

                    notification.contentView = contentView;
                    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                    mNotificationManager.notify(nID, notification);             
                }

                protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {     
                    long retData = 0;

                    OutputStream fosXSPDatabse = null;
                    InputStream inServerResponse = null;
                    URLConnection oURLConnection = null;
                    URL oURL = null;

                    try 
                    {
                        oURL = new URL(oFileManager.sExpiryLink);
                        oURLConnection = oURL.openConnection();

                        if (!(oURLConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

                        oURLConnection.connect();               
                        inServerResponse = new BufferedInputStream(oURL.openStream());
                        if (inServerResponse != null)
                        {
                            File fDirectory = new File(oFileManager.sAppFlesDirectory);
                            if (!fDirectory.exists())
                            {
                                if (!fDirectory.mkdir())
                                {}
                            }

                            fosXSPDatabse = new FileOutputStream(oFileManager.sAppFlesDirectory + "/" + oFileInfo.getFileName());
                            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                            int nCount = 0;
                            long lTotalDownloaded = 0;
                            int nTotalSize = oURLConnection.getContentLength();
                            while ((nCount = inServerResponse.read(data)) != -1) 
                            {
                                Log.d(String.valueOf(nID) + " - DoInBackground", String.valueOf(dNotificationbarProgress)); 
                                nDownloadCounter ++;
                                lTotalDownloaded += nCount;
                                dNotificationbarProgress = lTotalDownloaded * 100.0 / nTotalSize;
                                if (this.nDownloadCounter == 20 || dNotificationbarProgress == 100) {
                                    publishProgress(Integer.parseInt(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(dNotificationbarProgress).split("\\.")[0]));
                                    nDownloadCounter = 0;
                                }
                                fosXSPDatabse.write(data, 0, nCount);
                            }
                            inServerResponse.close();
                            fosXSPDatabse.flush();
                            fosXSPDatabse.close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {} 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {} 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {}
                    finally
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            inServerResponse.close();
                            fosXSPDatabse.flush();
                            fosXSPDatabse.close();

                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {}
                    }

                     return retData;
                 }

                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.d(String.valueOf(nID),"onProgressUpdate");
                        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, progress[0], false);
                        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_fileName, this.NotificationName);
                        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_percent, String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");

                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
                        File file = new File(this.sDownloadPath + this.NotificationName);
                        sMediaDataType = GSUtilities.sGetFileMIMEType(this.NotificationName);

                        notificationIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        notificationIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), sMediaDataType);

                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                        mNotificationManager.notify(this.nID, notification);    
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {}  
                 }

                protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
                    notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_fileName, "Successfully installed " + this.NotificationName);
                    notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_percent,  "100%");
                    mNotificationManager.notify(this.nID, notification);
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way to handle download multiple files is to use the Service.

Answer (score 0):

First, **it's never a good idea to silently ignore Exceptions**. You should at minumum log them to logcat. It think this is the problem.

Second, you're closing the streams multiple times.

Where are you calling the AsyncTask from?

If it's from an activity and the user navigates away from it, that might be terminated any time the OS wants to free up memory.

If it's from a service, that could be terminated too, but at least it is restarted later. If the service was started from a different process, such as a Sync Adapter, you should also post the PreExecute and PublishProgress and PostExecute code to the UI thread with the application looper handler as a message.

In adition, try limiting the number of concurrent downloads to max 3. Otherwise, an OutOfMemory might occur. You can do this with a BlockingQueue. If concurrency is not important, consider using an IntentService instead of an AsyncTask.

Comment: First : I am not removing the Exception its just to reduce the code in above.
Second : I am calling the AsynkTask from onclick ListView event.